# Argument of type '{ name: string | undefined; lastModified: Date | undefined; }[] | undefined' is not assignable parameter of type 'SetStateAction<any

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3

I'm building an application using React with typescript, here i want to upload xlsx files to s3 and view those files in the interface. this is my App.tsx file

*App.tsx*

```
function App() {
  const [uploadedFiles, setUploadFiles] = useState<FileData[]>([]);
  const [selectedFileData, setselectedFileData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [s3Files, setS3Files] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listS3Files = async () => {
      try {
        const s3Response =  await s3.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: bucketName }).promise();
        const files = s3Response.Contents?.map((object) => {
          return { 
            name: object.Key,
            lastModified: object.LastModified,
            };
        });
        setS3Files(files);
      }catch (error) {
        console.log('Error listing files in S3', error);
      }
    };
    listS3Files();
  }, []);

  const handleFileUpload = (data: any[]) => {
    const newFile: FileData = {
      name: 'Uploaded File',
      uploadDate: new Date(),
      data: data,
    };
    setUploadFiles([...uploadedFiles, newFile]);
  };

  const handleFileItemClick = (fileData: FileData) => {
    setselectedFileData(fileData.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Excel File Viewer</h1>
      <FileUploader onFileUpload={handleFileUpload} />
      <div>
        <h2>Uploaded Files</h2>
        <ul>
          {s3Files.map((file, index) => (
            <li key={index} onClick={() => handleFileItemClick(file)}>
              {file.name} - {file.lastModified.toDateString()}

            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      {selectedFileData.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h2>Selected File Data</h2>
          <FileDataViewer data={selectedFileData}/>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my code, the code line
`setS3Files(files);` giving me an error.

*Error:*

```
Argument of type '{ name: string | undefined; lastModified: Date | undefined; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<any[]>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<any[]>'.ts(2345)
```

do I need to fix anything in the line `const [s3Files, setS3Files] = useState<any[]>([]);` ? or how to fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: The error states that `files` are undefined, so the error is not in the setS3Files, but before that call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error its telling you the provided type from s3 for typescript is either an array of objects with some properties as listed in the object, or undefined. So the issue should be that `undefined` is not assignable to `any[]` which is correct.

So probably what you would want to do is check the response a bit, at least to remove `undefined`

So

```
if(files === undefined) return;
setS3Files(files);
```

instead of just set files directly.

You can also do any other checks to ensure data is as you want. But just removing `undefined` will resolved the type error since `{ name: string | undefined; lastModified: Date | undefined; }[]` is array so assignable to `any[]`

Hope it helps